# MYSQL query : Lower method in sql disables my index

Tags: mysql, sql, querydsl

- how can have my query be able to not differienciate between my lower and upper case column query but without using the `lower` method of sql?

  select * from
  User
  where
  lower(lusername)= 'abdel'
- i want to still be able to use my column name with any type of case (Abc, aBc, ABC,aBC..) but without using the `lower` function in my query sql because the `lower` disable my index that i put on my column name.

is there a way to do that ? thank you in advance

Comment: character data in mysql usually but not always uses a case insensitive collation; please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` and `select version()`

Comment: Please post your **actual** query. And **why** are you using `LOWER` in the first place? SQL is case-insensitive by default and you should use the `COLLATION` keyword to explicitly perform case-sensitive comparisons.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 2):

The default collation used in MySQL is case-insensitive. Therefore you don't need to use LOWER() if you are doing searching.

In other words, the following two queries should return the same results:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(name) = 'Abc';

SELECT ... FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Abc'
```

The latter query is able to optimize the query with an index, but the former can't.

Any expression or function call makes the search not "sargable" which means it can't use an index, because the optimizer can't know if that expression or function outputs have the same sort order as the index on the column.

---

Based on your comment below, I see you are using a collation utf8_bin, which is case-sensitive. This does improve performance a little bit over using a collation, so if performance is the only thing that's important in this case, I understand why you want to keep using that collation.

Here's a demo of using EXPLAIN to verify that it uses an index when you compare strings directly, but the binary collation does a case-sensitive search:

```
mysql> create table User (id serial primary key, lusername varchar(75) collate utf8_bin, created datetime, key(lusername));

mysql> explain select * from User where lusername = 'Abc';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User  | NULL       | ref  | lusername     | lusername | 228     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

But when we use a function like LOWER(), it can't use the index, and resorts to a table-scan:

```
mysql> explain select * from User where LOWER(lusername) = 'Abc';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

However, MySQL 5.7 has a feature to add a virtual column based on the expression, and index the virtual column:

```
mysql> alter table User add lower_lusername varchar(75) as (LOWER(lusername)), add key (lower_lusername);

mysql> explain select * from User where LOWER(lusername) = 'Abc';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User  | NULL       | ref  | lower_lusername | lower_lusername | 303     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

Alternatively, in MySQL 8.0, you can now get the index on the expression it without even adding a generated column:

```
mysql> alter table User add key ((LOWER(lusername)));

mysql> explain select * from User where LOWER(lusername) = 'Abc';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User  | NULL       | ref  | functional_index | functional_index | 228     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: i think i didn't explain very well my problem, the thing is that the name value can be Abc or abc or AbC or ABC, i want them all to be accepted knowing that the column name contain only the value abc.  without the lower if the value i send from my api to the database is Abc the query doesn't return the line with the name abc.

Comment: What's the collation defined on that column in your table? You can run SHOW CREATE TABLE to see.

Comment: varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL. The most important thing for is to keep the performance by using the indexes. using collate with binary my slow down my performance no ?

Comment: I tried to only add an new index lower but the query is not correct i don't know why: `alter table User add INDEX name_Lower (LOWER(name))`

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report? Also you are missing one level of nested parentheses. Look at my example carefully.

Comment: your solution is to add a new column. i don't need that. i just need a new index for my table. the new column is not a good thing to do. mysql 5.7

Comment: Then you can't use the solution I described for MySQL 8.0, unless you upgrade. You can't create an index on the column as is that is case-insensitive, unless you change the collation for that column. Those are your options. Good luck!

Comment: i need to change the collation of my column to what ?

Comment: Since your data is already encoded in utf8, I'd choose utf8_general_ci. It's MySQL's default collation for utf8 character set. The "ci" suffix means "case insensitive." See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-names.html